# What Bitcoin Wallet Can I Transfer BTC.com Private Keys To?

Tags: wallet, private-key, crypto-2.0

I have $43 of Bitcoin in a BTC.com wallet,: What wallet(s) can I transfer private keys too? (I can not send from BTC from wallet). What wallets are compatable?
Gary
shopansave52332gmail.com

Comment: Why can you not send from the wallet? In general transferring private keys is a very bad idea (you never know if the "sender" doesn't still have the keys).

Comment: Because I cannot. I get a message it is inefficient cannot send. And why is transferring private keys a bad idea? How else can I get my Bitcoin if I can not send it? It is the only way to recover it.